# Input split for Map function in Hadoop

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming, hadoop2, hadoop-partitioning

This is my first implementation in Hadoop. I am trying to implement my algorithm for probabilistic dataset in Map Reduce. In my dataset, last column will have some id(number of unique id's in the dataset is equal to the number of nodes in my cluster). I have to divide my dataset based on this column value and each set of records should be processed by each nodes in my cluster.

For example, if i have three nodes in my cluster, for the below dataset, one node should process all the records with id=1, another one with id=2, another one with id=3

```
name time  dept  id
--------------------
 b1  2:00pm z1   1
 b2  3:00pm z2   2
 c1  4:00pm y2   1
 b3  3:00pm z3   3
 c4  4:00pm x2   2
```

My map function should take each split as an input and process it in parallel in each node.

I am just trying to understand, which approach is possible to do in Hadoop. Either to input this dataset as a input for my map function and pass an additional argument with map to split the data based on id value. 
Or split the data beforehand to "n"(number of nodes) subsets and load it in to the nodes, if this is the correct approach, how it is possible to split the data based on value and load in different nodes. Because, what i understood from my readings is that hadoop split the data in to blocks based on the specified size. How can we specify a particular condition while loading. Just to add up, I am writing my program in python.

Someone please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing for you would probably be to have the mapper output the data with the id as key, which will guarantee that one reducer will get all the records for a specific id and then do your processing in the reducer phase.

For example,

**Input data:**

```
 b1  2:00pm z1   1
 b2  3:00pm z2   2
 c1  4:00pm y2   1
 b3  3:00pm z3   3
 c4  4:00pm x2   2
```

**Mapper code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    cols = line.split("\t")
    key = cols[-1]
    print key + "\t" + line
```

**Map output:**

```
 1  b1  2:00pm z1   1
 2  b2  3:00pm z2   2
 1  c1  4:00pm y2   1
 3  b3  3:00pm z3   3
 2  c4  4:00pm x2   2
```

**Reducer 1 input:**

```
 1  b1  2:00pm z1   1
 1  c1  4:00pm y2   1
```

**Reducer 2 input:**

```
 2  b2  3:00pm z2   2
```

**Reducer 3 input:**

```
 3  b3  3:00pm z3   3
```

**Reducer code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    cols = line.split("\t")
    orig_line = "\t".join(cols[1:])
    # do stuff...
```

Note that this way a single reducer might get several keys, but the data will be ordered and you can  control the number of reducers with the *mapred.reduce.tasks* option.

**EDIT**
If you want to collect your data in the reducer per key you can do something like this (not sure it will run as-is but you get the idea)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
def process_data(key_id, data_list):
   # data_list has all the lines for key_id

last_key = None
data = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    cols = line.split("\t")
    key = cols[0]
    if last_key and key != last_key:
        process_data(last_key, data)
        data = []
    orig_line = "\t".join(cols[1:])
    data.append(orig_line)
    last_key = key
process_data(last_key, data)
```

If you aren't worried about running out of memory in the reducer step you can simplify the code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
def process_data(key_id, data_list):
   # data_list has all the lines for key_id

all_data = defaultdict(list)
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    cols = line.split("\t")
    key = cols[0]
    orig_line = "\t".join(cols[1:])
    all_data[key].append(orig_line)
for key, data in all_data.iteritems():
    process_data(key, data)
```

Comment: Single reducer should not get several keys since i want my algorithm to run on each dataset records(records belonging to one key), this will affect my output. And after getting outputs from my algorithm on all keys, i need to reduce it further by finding minimal subsets of the output. how can i achieve that?

Comment: Even though the reducer will get more than one key, you can process it however you like. For example, collect the data until you get to the next key (remember, it's ordered) and at that point you process the data for the previous key.
Using this method, in order to reduce it further you would need to run another map/reduce job on the output, or just run a python script on the output data (if it's small enough).

Comment: That makes sense. cool. Is it possible for a single key to be split up to more than one reducer? Because i need all the records for single key at a time to run my algorithm

Comment: No, hadoop guarantees that all records for single key will be processed by the same reducer.

Comment: Thats great, after i get the input to reducer, i want only this "b1  2:00pm z1" from the reduce input "1  b1  2:00pm z1   1", i have added 1 to denote my dataset number, in that case how can i manipulate this in python, because i am not sure what format reducer gets the input and how to parse it.

Comment: And when you say for line in sys.stdin: in reduce code, does that handles each line at a time or all data belonging to each key at a time, becasue i need all data for a particular key at a time to process. If i can collect all data for a key once and process, how can i implement that. Any help?

Comment: In streaming you will get one line in stdin per output line from the mapper (which is different from native java where the reducer will get all the data for each key at once). You will need to collect the data yourself, but it's pretty easy. Just put it into a dictionary in the `for line in sys.stdin` phase and then iterate through the dictionary.

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps a lot, final question, you mentioned something - "collect the data until you get to the next key", is there a specific function for this in python?

Comment: No, not really. It's just an optimization if you can't fit the entire dataset into memory. Collect stuff into a list until you hit the next key, then call process_data(my_data) on the previous key. Just putting the data into a dictionary and then processing it separately once all the lines are digested is simpler.

Comment: Naah. What i was asking is how to achieve this logic - "Collect until you hit the next key", is there a function to get data for a single key or i have to do it manually, if you could write up a code, that would be great.

Comment: I've amended the answer to add the requested code. Hope that helps!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61349/discussion-between-jeeva-and-nonnib).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, the best way is to load your dataset into a **hive** table, then write **UDF** in python. After that, do something like this:

```
select your_python_udf(name, time, dept, id) from table group by id;
```

This is look like reduce phase, so you, maybe, need this before launching the query

```
set mapred.reduce.tasks=50;
```

How to create custom UDF:

[Hive Plugins](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HivePlugins)

[Create Function](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateFunction)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the explanation, but could you clarify how can i make use of the data then. This should be my map step as i have to run my algorithm on each subset(based on id) in each node. Everything should not run in same node. Then the outputs of all these nodes will be used in reduce phase to process and get the combined output.